# Calculate number of minutes for specific day from a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that holds vehicle activity data. There is a start date and end date columns in the table. I wish to construct a query that will show the amount of time in minutes that each vehicle is active or working on a particular day.  My problem is that the time between the start date and end date may span a number of days.

Example:

```
dwVehicleIDFK    StartDate           EndDate             Minutes    HrsMins
731              18/09/2019 08:00    18/09/2019 13:00    300        05:00
797              18/09/2019 08:00    18/09/2019 12:00    240        04:00
687              17/09/2019 16:00    17/09/2019 21:00    300        05:00
826              17/09/2019 16:00    17/09/2019 21:00    300        05:00
734              18/09/2019 10:00    18/09/2019 15:30    330        05:30
843              18/09/2019 14:00    18/09/2019 18:00    240        04:00
662              18/09/2019 09:00    18/09/2019 14:00    300        05:00
662              17/09/2019 09:00    17/09/2019 14:00    300        05:00
662              16/09/2019 09:00    16/09/2019 14:00    300        05:00
817              18/09/2019 14:00    19/09/2019 08:00    1080       18:00
```

In the data above the vehicle with the ID of 817 extends over two days. How would I get the query to return the time period for the 18/09 only or up until midnight on the 18/09?

The query to return the data above:

```sql
Select
    dwVehicleIDFK,
    StartDate,
    EndDate,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Convert(DateTime, StartDate, 103),
    Convert(DateTime, EndDate, 103)) as Minutes,
    CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 
        Convert(DateTime, StartDate, 103),
        Convert(DateTime, EndDate, 103)), 0), 114) as HrsMins
from 
    VehHistory
```

Comment: Use a `WHERE`. What have you tried? Also, why are you doing `Convert(DateTime, StartDate, 103)` in your `SELECT`? Is `StartDate` a `varchar`? If so, that's a bigger problem and should be fixed.

Comment: I can use a where against the StartDate but the EndDate is written in by another process.

Comment: Ok, I see. This sounds like you're likely going to need a calendar table. That doesn't, however ,answer about the data type of your data. *are* they a `varchar`? If so, that's a big problem

Comment: Do you have a table of dates (calendar table)? Can you create one for this?

Comment: They are varchar but i could write them to a temporary table as DateTime values!

Comment: I could create a Calendar table but how would that help in this instance?

Comment: You should fix your table and ALWAYS store them as datetime.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: The problem is that I have inherited the table structure.  The original table holds the date as a date value and the time as a varchar  '09:00' etc. I am working with a temporary table so I can change this to datetime values and convert the data when I construct the query.

Comment: Maybe you can add a computed column to the table? Then you don't have to wrestle with conversions all the time.

Comment: I think that is possibly the best way forward, I will do some work on that approach and see how it goes.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you loaded the data for the specified date @Day and converted the start/end date to datetime in temp table #temp:

```
Select
    dwVehicleIDFK,
    StartDate,
    EndDate,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CASE WHEN StartDate<@Day THEN @Day ELSE StartDate END,
    CASE WHEN EndDate>DATEADD(DAY,1,@Day) THEN DATEADD(DAY,1,@Day) ELSE EndDate END) AS UsedMinutes
from #temp;
```

Comment: Sorry Peter,  I have converted the values to DateTimes and when I try your query I get an error: ncorrect syntax near ','. I can't work out where this is being caused!

Comment: I Missed the END for the CASE expression. Can you try it again?

Comment: Still has an issue with 'THEN @Day ELSE ColDate,' There is a red squiggly under the comma that follows ColDate!